# How to efficiently replace characters in string with given mapping rule?

Tags: c#, .net, string, algorithm

I have a mapping rule like:

'a' -> 'b'

'b' -> 'c'

'h' -> 'a'

'd' -> 'y'

I need to replace all characters in given string by this rule using C#.NET.

For example, according to the rule above string "**asdfgh**" will be replaced with "**bsyfga**".

Is there any efficient ways how to do this, except of just iterating string and replacing character one by one? I think in case of long strings it will consume a lot of time.

It's **not** allowed to make "chain" replacements like 'a'->'b'->'c'.

Comment: Please, share your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: O(n) time and O(n) space with a StringBuilder and a Dictionary.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it efficient , but if not, just create a function with one string parameter and start to remplace lettre by lettre using replace methode of string class, of course you should be carful of what  to start with, for me i'll start replacing with 'd', than 'b' thant 'a' that 'h', good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` for mapping.

First, declare a dictionary for mappings :

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char> {{'a', 'b'}, {'b', 'c'}, {'h', 'a'}, {'d', 'y'}};
```

Then get values from it :

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var character in input)
  {
   if (dictionary.TryGetValue(character, out var value))
     stringBuilder.Append(value);
  }

 return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: You can also simply index and replace characters inside the StringBuilder. `var sb = new StringBuilder(input); ... sb[i] = 'x';`